# Krylov-Schur algorithm for eigenpairs

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm currently studying Krylov-Schur method from Stewart, using "Matrix Algorithms, Volume II: Eigensystems" G.W. Stewart and I have a question concerning the method:

#### Background :

Brief explanation of the setting: The method consists in generating a $n\times k$ matrix relation "of order $k$" of the form $$AU_k = U_k B_k + u_{k+1}b_{k+1}^H$$

Where $(U_k \hspace{0.1cm} u_{k+1})$ are linearly independent and wlog orthonormal, while the other are arbitrary. This is called Krylov decomposition. Now by similarity we can take $B_k$ to its Schur form without changing the space spanned by the column of $(U_k \hspace{0.1cm} u_{k+1})$, which we will call a Krylov-Schur decomposition of order $k$ : $$A\tilde{U_k} = \tilde{U_k} S_k + u_{k+1}\tilde{b_{k+1}}^H$$ where the $S$ stresses the triangularity of $S_k$. Now a step of the Krylov Schur algorithm divides into two steps :

1. An *expansion phase*.
2. A *contraction phase*.

In brief: The expansion phase extends the Krylov Schur decomposition of order $k$ into a Krylov decomposition of order $m$ which converts into a Krylov Schur decomposition of order $m$ using [Arnoldi iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration):

$$A\tilde{U_m} = \tilde{U_m} S_k + u_{m+1}\tilde{b_{m+1}}^H$$

wlog we can assume that the $k$ needed eigenvalues are placed in the first $k$ elements of the diagonal of $S_k$. Now the problem is how to set the first $k$ components of $\tilde{b_{m+1}}^H$ to $0$ in order to deflate the decomposition obtain $$A\tilde{U}_k = \tilde{U}_k S_{k,k}$$

From here we can apply the [Rayleigh Ritz procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Ritz_method) in order to compute the needed eigenpairs

#### First Question:

> What is the theory behind this machinery? I don't understand why
> deflating and expanding the decomposition should converge, i.e
> decreasing residual norm(in order to set the first component of
> $b_{k+1}$ to $0$). The book doesn't seem to specify the convergence of
> the method, the only material I can find are the following theorems:

---

[image]

---

My thoughts on this:

This theorem should just be probably be the "optimality" of Rayeleigh quotient.

I think this one in the specific case studied this theorem says that the residual $$A\tilde{U_m} - \tilde{U_m} S_k$$ minimizes the norm since $S_k$ being the Schur form is $\tilde{U_m}^H A\tilde{U_m}$ thanks to the orthogonality of the column of $\tilde{U_m}$ wrt $u_{m+1}$(Arnoldi iteration).

---

#### Second Problem:

> I don't understand how the following description of Rayleigh Ritz
> procedure adapts to the method of Krylov-Schur (also related to
> question $1$, since I don't understand the convergence of the method)

---

[image]

---

The problem here is that in p.$282$ is said that $W$ is taken to be orthogonal. As far as I understand $M$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues needed and $W$ should be the matrix whose columns are the eigenvector of the Schur form $S_k$.

Since $A$ in general will be far from normal, I don't understand such a request in that case, being impossible in general. Any help in order to clarify this detail would be appreciated. If my understanding is wrong, who's $M$ and $W$ in the Krylov-Schur method?

**My thoughts:**

In my method I'd like to take $$A\tilde{U_m} = \tilde{U_m} S_k + u_{m+1}\tilde{b_{m+1}}^H$$

truncate to the order $k$

$$A\tilde{U_k} = \tilde{U_k} S_k,k + u_{k+1}\tilde{b_{k+1}}^H$$

and being able to afirm that the residual are small soon or later. If not small enough repeat until convergence (guaranteed by some theorem I'm not aware of) expanding and deflating. Of course I can take the $k\times k$ matrix $Z_k$ eigenvector of $S_{k,k}$ and the associated diagonal matrix $M_k$ so that $\|A \tilde{U}_k Z_k  - \tilde{U}_k Z_k M\|$ is small since the individual are small, but how this is supported by theory?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I followed your advice, thanks.